# CakePHP: drop-down list with database fields

Tags: cakephp

I've got this relationship between two models:

Snippet belongsTo SnippetCategory
SnippetCategory hasMany Snippet

I need a drop-down list of SnippetCategories when I add a new Snippet. For this, I've got the following code:

```
//Snippet.php
public $belongsTo = array(
'SnippetCategory' => array(
    'className' => 'SnippetCategory',
    'foreignKey' => 'snippet_category_id'));

//SnippetCategory.php
public $hasMany = array(
'Snippet' => array(
    'className' => 'Snippet',
    'foreignKey' => 'snippet_category_id',
    'dependent' => true));

//SnippetsController.php
public function add() {
$categories = $this->Snippet->SnippetCategory->find('list');
$this->set(compact('categories'));
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->request->data['Snippet']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if ($this->Snippet->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Snippet saved.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}

//Snippets/add.ctp
// ...html...
echo $this->Form->input('categories', array(
'tabindex' => 2));
// ...html...
```

But I'm getting a "Call to a member function find() on a non-object" error. I know it has to be some stupid error, but I'm not able to find what I'm doing wrong...

Please, someone could help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try just calling the relevant model (Snippet is linked to it anyway) `$this->SnippetCategory->find('list');`

Comment: I would guess there's another find() you're not showing us.

Comment: @scrowler I've tried it, even ´$this->SnippetCategory->Snippet->find('list');´ but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Dave I've edited my question with the full SnippetsCategory.php code. There is no other find() in the add function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should post the whole code from the Snippet and SnippetCategory model. Maybe there's something that is causing this oddly behavior that is not shown in this snippet of code.

The error is quite straight forward, SnippetCategory is not initialized.

You can always use:

```
$this->loadModel('SnippetCategory');
$this->SnippetCategory->find('list');
```

But it's not the smarttest way because SnippetCategory model must be initialized with the Snippet model

Comment: I've just read the comments, and realized this is the full code for Snippet and SnippetCategory models. My bad

Comment: You are right! I just needed to add the ´$this->loadModel('SnippetCategory');´ line. But I don't understand why I have to load the model if both models are linked. Is it because Snippet is not the main model? If I were trying to access to the Snippet model from SnippetCategory, I wouldn't need to use loadModel, isn't it?

Comment: No, You should be able to access SnippetCategory from Snippet, and vice versa. Thats why I thought you did something in your model. my suggestion is you check your database references, and try to cake bake model again :D

Comment: I'm double checking my database tables, but I cannot find anything wrong... What name should I use for foreign key? `snippet_category_id` is fine? I think I'm following all name conventions for the automagic...

Comment: could you give me the database tables names? Is it: Snippet => snippets, SnippetCategory => snippet_categories and one in between snippets_categories?

Comment: I have `snippets` for Snippet and `snippet_categories` for SnippetCategory, but nothing in between because it's a hasOne/belongsTo relation. `snippet` has a field named `snippet_category_id`, because it `belongsTo snippet_categories`. It's ok this way? Thanks!

Comment: tell you what, open the Snippet model and try to put the 
"@property SnippetCategory $SnippetCategory" annotaion on top of your model file.

Comment: I suppose I have to write `/* @property SnippetCategory $SnippetCategory */` just before `class Snippet extends...` isn't it? And then delete the line `$this->loadModel('SnippetCategory');` from my SnippetsController.php. Well, it didn't work, still getting the non-object problem... :(